# Unable to interact with Stripe iframe element via Cypress

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments, cypress

We are using Cypress for web UI automation, where during signup, we have Stripe iframe, which loads fine during Manual interaction, but via Cypress, body of the underlying is not loaded. This was working till last week and all of a sudden it stopped working

Below is the iFrame and corresponding DOM when checked manually
[Manual Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOVqN.png)
[DOM Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QitvV.png)

Below is the iFrame and corresponding DOM via Cypress
[UI when ran from Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRnaL.png)
[DOM when ran from Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5xjZ.png)

This is the Locator I have used

```
cy.iframe('iframe[title="Secure card number input frame"]').find('input[class="InputElement is-empty Input Input--empty"]')
```

This was working till last week and stopped working with an error

````
AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: `iframe[title="Secure card number input frame"]`, but never found it.```
````

Comment: You shouldn't be testing third parties components. Your tests must be focusing on your own UIs because you are testing a production ready UI (e.g. Stripe Element) in an automated framework (bot like) which may be blocked due to security checks. You should mock third parties during your tests and not test them.

Comment: @os4m37 thanks for your reply, I understand your point, we have 3rd party fields implemented in our UI as Iframes, and it is during the signup process. so thought of including it

Answer (score 0):

I also include filling stripe elements in our e2e testing. We are using plugin called cypress-plugin-stripe-elements and it's works fine so far. Maybe if you want to give it a try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-plugin-stripe-elements